# Invalid Image Path - No Image found AppIcon120x120

Tags: objective-c, ios8, xcode6

I'm using Xcode 6 and Assets Catalogue to manage my App Icons. Or at least so I thought!

I'm trying to validate my Archive, but keep getting this message:

[image: Problem with Validations]

I have an image of 120x120 in the Assets Catalogue under AppIcon (although labeled as CarPlay iOS8). In fact I have lots and lots of images under AppIcon. I know the 120x120 is there. I promise.

To check, I have deleted it. Added it again. Deleted all the AppIcons, added them again. Clean built.

Still the same error message.

I really am at a loss as to know what to do.

I've looked in the plist and there is no mention of CFBundleIcons in there ..

So, any help would be gratefully received.

Comment: provide the screenshot of AppIcons from Images.xcassets...

Comment: Will do. At the moment, I removed the CarPlay icon and it's now verified as working. Screen shot to follow ...

Comment: I'm getting this too. If I delete the CarPlay icon it validates.

Comment: Confirmed: Deleting CarPlay icon fixes this

Comment: Will removing that keep your app from working in CarPlay?

Comment: I couldn't tell you, thankfully my App won't be one you'll want to use in your car ;)

Comment: Removing CarPlay icons worked for me as well.  Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Remove the CarPlay icon from your AppIcon image assets.

Comment: If you have a CarPlay icon, then Xcode generates an Info.plist including CBundleIcons that references AppIcon120x120. This is clearly wrong... If you delete the carplay icon, the AppIcon120x120 drops out of Info.plist and everything works properly.

Answer (score 5):

If you actually want or need a 120x120 icon anyway, this can also be fixed by including a 120x120 icon named `AppIcon120x120.png` in your bundle as a regular file (outside of the asset catalog), *in addition to* the CarPlay entry in the icon asset.